# Fareham to london

Tags: uk, trains, national-rail

I need to visit someone in Reading I have an open return from Fareham to London. Can I disembark at Reading for a few hours then get back on a train using the same ticket?

Answer (score 12):

The term you are looking for is "breaking your journey". I am assuming by an "open" ticket you are referring to an anytime ticket.

In the UK for anytime tickets you can break your journey.  National rail [notes that](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ticket_types/46544.aspx):

> Break of journey
>
> You may start, break and resume, or end your journey at any intermediate station along the route of travel.

So the next question - is Fareham to Reading to London a permitted route? You would not be allowed to say from Fareham to Inverness to London. So which routes are permitted?  Where is the line drawn?

I am assuming you have an any permitted ticket without any restrictions, you can tell if your ticket has any restrictions by looking in the lower right and corner. Have a [look at this](https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5598/15280434598_97601ddd83_o.jpg) which has restriction code FE. You can have a look at the meaning of a restriction code by going to `http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/YOURCODE` (so for the ticket above,  http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/FE) and see if they apply.

But for tickets with no explicit routing restriction, where do we draw the line? If you have a look at the [ATOC website](http://data.atoc.org/rp_calc) then you will see your journey is equivalent to a Portsmouth Group to London Group ticket.

You can then have a look at [this PDF](http://iblocks-rg-publication.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yellow_pages.pdf) (very large - 2,270 pages). You will find this line on page 1,555 and at the time of my writing it says:

```
BB+BL   CW+LB   CW+LF   PD   SW
```

You should interpret each cell as an or, but each "+" as an and. So you could use maps BB then BL, or just PD,  etc.

You can see the maps [on the ATOC website](http://data.atoc.org/routeing-maps). The rules for how to follow the maps are:

1. Tracing must start at one of the ends of the route code.
2. All maps must be used.
3. Maps must be used in strict sequence, first to last or last to first, for a return journey.
4. Tracing may move from map to map only at a point where the two maps touch.
5. Once route tracing has left a map it cannot return to it.
6. Journeys may not double back except between stations which are members of a routeing point group for interchange or unless [an easement](http://www.atoc.org/clientfiles/files/easements.pdf) permits it.

So lets have a look at what the maps mean in your case?  I have done a (terrible) overlay of the BB (Blue) and BL (Red) maps to make this easier.

[image: BB and BL maps overlaid]

So we can see a route traveling from Fareham to Reading and then into Paddington while following the rules above. As such: yes, you can break your journey at any intermediate point, and you can travel via Reading on your ticket (assuming it is any permitted). Note that you need to follow the maps exactly, you cannot simply get any train, it must pass through (with or without stopping) the routes listed.

Just a quick additional note that the technology behind ticket barriers is quite old now and can have problems. Since there doesn't seem to be any reason why you would travel from Fareham to London this way (unless you wanted to stop off) then the ticket barriers at Reading may reject your ticket. I would leave more time then usual to arrive back at the station, and show your ticket to a member of staff instead of putting it through the barriers if at all possible.

Comment: Reading isn't an intermediate station between Fareham and London though.

Comment: @IanCook Not on the direct line to London Waterloo, but Farnham to London Paddington changing at Southampton or Basingstoke and Reading does seem to be a permissible route. The OP will have to double check that will work for their specific ticket though.

Comment: Also, note that Reading station has automated ticket barriers, which @user90217's ticket could either not work on, or be eaten by. They will have to search out a human.

Comment: Thank you IanCook and Origimbo - I have calcified and showed on the routing guide a valid route. I had assumed it was clearly allowed as I live a lot further north then this!

Comment: +1 from me for an excellent summary of how to use the routing guides, which is a skill that any serious user of the railways in the UK must eventually master.  I hope you'll forgive my tidying-up your answer a bit, and I hope I've made it a little easier to read.

Comment: @MadHatter agreed, but bear in mind that this is slightly simplified - there are some more difficulties, for example in this case both stations are members of routeing groups, and the procedure for what to do if that isn't the case is a little more complex.

Comment: +1'd the answer, it's very good. Might be worth adding to your answer that for practical purposes, this means you would get to Reading by catching a South Western Railway service direct from Fareham to Basingstoke, and then changing there onto either a local (GWR) train to Reading or a CrossCountry one (depending on which is first). Once you're finished your visit in Reading, it looks like you must then catch a GWR service to London Paddington (this is the fastest way to London from Reading in any case).

Comment: Most people would probablly also describe and off-peak ticket as "open". Be aware that for off-peak tickets break of journey may or may not be allowed (In this case I can't see any restriction against it, but be aware in general).

Comment: Thank you @MadHatter for the improvements - of course I don't mind and thanks again. And yes this is simplified and was only designed to show the sections relivent. I'm a little busy this week but I'll shortly try and write up a proper guide, but anyone else feel free if you want.

Comment: @skifans What a good idea! I might give this a go myself, actually, if you don't mind; I do feel we're missing a comprehensive and general guide to UK rail ticketing here...

Comment: Of course I don't mimd @Muzer, let us know if you want a hand or for me just to read through.

Comment: @skifans well, I just started writing an answer for a comprehensive "how do I know on which trains my ticket is valid" question (comprising time-based restrictions, operator restrictions, and route restrictions), and I'm already over the 30,000 character limit... I think I need to split the question into multiple sub-questions! Bloody hell, UK rail ticketing is complicated.

Comment: @Munzer great, I feel those are funnidmetaly 2 different questions. I've made a chat at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/87944/uk-train-tickets if you want to talk more about it as I feel a bit bad doing so here.